# How to display notification when NFC is detected

Tags: android, react-native

I have a NFC tag with specific mime and I would like to display just notification, that NFC tag was found, when NFC is close to phone.
How can achieve this?

I added to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/my-stream" />
</intent-filter>
```

But this brings my app to foreground.
How can I keep my app in the background and just display notification tapping on which will open app?